# How parse json object into kotlin data class with custom data type?

Tags: json, kotlin, parsing

With default data types like String, Long, BigDecimal, and etc. Works fine, But with custom data types errors occures.

```
fun main() {

    class Quantity(doubleValue: Double) : BigDecimal(doubleValue) {
        override fun toByte(): Byte = super.toInt().toByte()
        override fun toChar(): Char = super.toInt().toChar()
        override fun toShort(): Short = super.toInt().toShort()
    }

    data class CustomDataType(
        val customDataType: Quantity
    )


    val testJson = jacksonObjectMapper()
        .valueToTree<JsonNode>(
            CustomDataType(
                Quantity(200.toDouble())
            )
        ).toString()

    jacksonObjectMapper().readValue(testJson, CustomDataType::class.java)
}
```

Output ->

Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Cannot deserialize Class com.test.project.server.utils.ApiJsonTypesKt$main$CustomDataType (of type local/anonymous) as a Bean
at [Source: (String)"{"customDataType":0.00200000000000000004163336342344337026588618755340576171875}"; line: 1, column: 1]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:309)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:268)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:244)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.findValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:142)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.findRootValueDeserializer(DeserializationContext.java:491)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._findRootDeserializer(ObjectMapper.java:4669)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4478)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3434)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3402)
at com.test.project.server.utils.ApiJsonTypesKt.main(ApiJsonTypes.kt:37)
at com.test.project.server.utils.ApiJsonTypesKt.main(ApiJsonTypes.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot deserialize Class com.test.project.server.utils.ApiJsonTypesKt$main$CustomDataType (of type local/anonymous) as a Bean
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.isPotentialBeanType(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:883)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerFactory.createBeanDeserializer(BeanDeserializerFactory.java:137)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer2(DeserializerCache.java:414)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:349)
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:264)
... 9 more